# Delphi dll function to C#

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke

With a compiled Delphi dll, one of the functions declared is

Mydll.dll

```
type
 TInfo = array [0..255] of byte;

type
 public
   function GetInfo(Memadr, Infolen: Integer): TInfo;
```

what is the DLLImport format to use this in C#?

Comment: It seems like you extracted the function declaration off from a higher level declaration, probably a class declaration. I suspect this because of the hanging `type` and `public` words. It is very relevant to know for the appropiate import definition.

Comment: Check this link:

[Calling a delphi DLL method from C# Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200521/calling-a-delphi-dll-method-from-c-code)

Answer (score 4):

I'd do it like this:

**Delphi**

```
type
  TInfo = array [0..255] of byte;

procedure GetInfo(Memadr, Infolen: Integer; var Result: TInfo); stdcall;
```

**C#**

```
[DllImport(@"testlib.dll")]
static extern void GetInfo(int Memadr, int Infolen, byte[] result);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] result = new byte[256];
    GetInfo(0, result.Length, result);
    foreach (byte b in result)
        Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```

You need to get the calling conventions to match. I've gone for `stdcall` which is the default for P/invoke (that's why it's not specified in the P/invoke signature).

I'd avoid returning the array as a function return value.  It's easier to marshall it this way as a parameter.

In fact in general, if you want to get away from fixed size buffers you could do it like this:

**Delphi**

```
procedure GetInfo(Memadr, Infolen: Integer; Buffer: PByte); stdcall;
```

Then, to fill out the buffer, you'd need to use some pointer arithmetic or something equivalent.

Comment: +1 however... The OP might be actually trying to export a "Procedure of Object" and call it as a Procedure. (Why else would he have put a public keyword right above his method signature).

Comment: @Warren You can't export `procedure of object` because you can't export Delphi objects. To export an OOP interface you are looking at COM or opaque handles to object references.

Comment: Of course you can't, and I know that, but I wonder what the "public" in the OP's "sample code" is trying to tell us...  public isn't a valid keyword at the top level unit scope. This signals OP confusion.

Comment: @David: I agree with Warren. It looks as if the code is not the orginal code he is actually using. The fact that there is a "public" in there might mean he extracted that code from an actual class declaration. If he actually wants to export a method, what you described won't work, of course.

Comment: @rudy @warren You may be right. I assumed the block was the handling of the byte buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Need to correct an error in my original post,

```
type
 TInfo = array [0..255] of byte;

implementation
 function GetInfo(Memadr, Infolen: Integer): TInfo;


procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var Data: TInfo;
    i: integer;
    s: string;
begin
for i:=0 to 255 do Data[i]:=0;
Data:=GetInfo($04,12);
if (Data[1]=0) then
  begin StatusBar1.SimpleText:='No Data'; exit; end;
s:='';
for i:=1 to 8 do
  s:=s+Chr(Data[i+1]);
Edit3.Text:=s;
end;
```